# Import data into SQL Server using BCP utility (export the log file with the error records and continue inserting with the normal records)

Tags: sql-server, import, triggers, bcp

I have a data set and want to import it into my database with the condition:

1. In case there is a record that cannot be imported, it can be extracted into a log
2. Although existing records can not be imported but still allow import of records that can be imported (other records) and continue to process

Currently I use the BCP utility to import data into the table from the csv file with:

```
bcp table_name IN C:\Users\09204086121\Desktop\data.csv  -T -c -o C:\Users\09204086121\Desktop\logOut.log -e C:\Users\09204086121\Desktop\errOut.log
```

It just satisfies my condition 1 above.
I need that when the record has error (duplicate primary key,...), write to log (1) and continue to insert into the table the other normal records (2).

I came up with the idea that combining trigger with bcp, after creating a trigger and adding the parameter `-h "FIRE_TRIGGERS"` to the bcp statement, the insert will ignore records that have the same key but it won't write to the log.

This is my trigger.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [PKGORDERCOMMON].[T_ImportData] ON [PKGORDERCOMMON].[IF_R_BUNRUI1]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN         
    --Insert non duplicate records
    INSERT INTO [IF_R_BUNRUI1]
    (
        SYSTEM_KB, 
        BUNRUI1_CD, 
        BUNRUI1_KANJI_NA, 
        BUNRUI1_KANA_NA, 
        CREATE_TS
    )
    SELECT SYSTEM_KB, 
        BUNRUI1_CD, 
        BUNRUI1_KANJI_NA, 
        BUNRUI1_KANA_NA, 
        CREATE_TS
    FROM inserted i
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM [IF_R_BUNRUI1] c
        WHERE c.BUNRUI1_CD = i.BUNRUI1_CD
        AND c.SYSTEM_KB = i.SYSTEM_KB
    );
END;
```

Is there anyone who can help me.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: hi why not add Unique Constraint couple (BUNRUT1_CD, SYSTEM_KB) with this constraint you doesn't have to add this Trigger..

Comment: @Sanpas a unique constraint will only prevent duplicates, but it will also stop the bulk copy process. And certainly won't log duplicates.

Comment: Yes i understand this but in bcp have some other option (arguments like '-e "errorfile.txt"') inserting duplicate key it's not only log but constraint error
We can see all option in this page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I want to use bcp to import data into the table. If the record fails, then write to the log, other records will continue to be inserted into the table. How to use bcp that can satisfy the 2 cases above?

Comment: i think you have to add : -h "CHECK_CONSTRAINTS"
Specifies that all constraints on the target table or view must be checked during the bulk-import operation. Without the CHECK_CONSTRAINTS hint, any CHECK, and FOREIGN KEY constraints are ignored, and after the operation the constraint on the table is marked as not-trusted.

Comment: As best I can make out you have accomplished point 1? But you haven't attempted point 2? So have an attempt at point 2 and ask when stuck? Logging is a very general term. There are so many options. The most obvious is to write to a table and then extract it later.

Comment: @Sanpas  add : -h "CHECK_CONSTRAINTS"  it extracted into a log, but other records can't continue to be inserted into the table

Comment: @Dale K  It seems that when using the trigger, the bcp has skipped duplicate keys so it cannot log out which records are duplicated.

Comment: Why can't you just `select * from table where EXISTS (select from Inserted)` within your trigger,

Comment: @TieuDuongTu : other option can try to add (max error handling) if it's not set max error was 10 
Add -m 10000 for trying https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15#m

Answer (score 0):

BCP is not meant for what you are asking it to do (separate good and bad records). For instance, bcp -e option has a limit to how many records it will show. Im not sure if this limit is tied to the "max errors" option, but regardless there is a limit.

Your best option is to load all the records and address bad data in t-sql.

Load all records in such a way to ignore conversion errors. Either:

1. load entire line from file into a single, large varchar column. Parse out columns and qc data as needed.
   or
2. load all columns from source file into generic varchar columns with large enough size to accomodate your source data.

Either way, when done, use t-sql to inspect your data and split among good/bad records.